# UpdateAsync method is not work in web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am create small demo for user registration using web api mvc c#.i am register Succeeded for user using '**Register**' in web api.now i want to using this method also edit this user by id so how can do that i don't know any one know please let me know. i my code i will manage add/edit call in one method so i will first check the condition on id is null then add and id is not null then go for the edit but how can edit this record and role.

here this my method :

```
  [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {            
        try
        {
            if (model.Id == "")
            {          
              //here is for add user method         
                var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email,PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber };
                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var UsersContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
                    var res = UsersContext.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == user.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
                    var UserId = res.Id;
                    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(UserId, model.UserRole);
                    return Ok(result);
                }
                return Ok(result);
            }
            else
            {
               //here i want write edit code
                var UsersContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
                var Team = UsersContext.Users.Find(model.Id);

                Team.UserName = model.UserName;
                Team.Email = model.Email;
                Team.PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber;
                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(Team); //here getting error.
                return Ok(result);  
            }                
            return Ok("Done");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: @Bansanta Matia have you any idea how can edit user?

Comment: What error you are getting in update ?

Comment: Attaching an entity of type 'abc.Models.ApplicationUser' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are newand have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method orthe 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

First check whether you are passing values to all **required field** or not.

Keep this **UserStore** after your controller class calling braces **{**.

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
 UserStore<IdentityUser> myUserStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new 
                                    ApplicationDbContext());
 //rest code
```

Then inside your Register() Post method, do like this bellow,

```
if (model.Id == "")
 {
  //Add new user code
 }
else
 {
  var context = myUserStore.Context as ApplicationDbContext;
  var Team = context.Users.Find(model.Id);
  //change the field value what ever you want to update
  context.Users.Attach(Team);
  context.Entry(Team).State = EntityState.Modified;
  context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
  await context.SaveChangesAsync();
  return Ok("Updated");
 }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: "UserManager" is a class?

Comment: Write like this new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore); Let me know whether it's working or not

Comment: still getting same : 'Attaching an entity of type 'abc.Models.ApplicationUser' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are newand have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method orthe 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.'

Comment: hi i am try with your solution but still getting same error can you please know how can resolved this error

Comment: np :) await context.SaveChangesAsync(); here i m getting error 'cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.identity.IdenetituyResult' '

Comment: Yes. because this will return a int value and you are assigning it to IdentityResult result. That's why. You can remove IdentityResult result and return some success method, like, return Ok("Updated"); Check once and let me know whether its updating or not.

Comment: Remove this one, IdentityResult result =. It will be only await context.SaveChangesAsync();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139944/discussion-between-coderwill-and-basanta-matia).